# (Tkinter/Python) How to check for things in textfile and have different outcomes based on results?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently having some trouble with checking if things are written down in my textfile.

In my code, I check if "1" is in my storefile.txt file. If "1" isn't in the textfile, signalling that the user has opened the code for the first time, Tkinter asks for the user's name and puts in "1" (signalling that the user has opened the code before). If not, Tkinter says "Welcome back," and the user's inputted name.

However, even after I open the code after the first time, the code acts like "1" isn't even in the storefile, even though it is. The code asks for my name and prints "1" again, so I end up having more than 1 "1"s in my storefile and never reach to the "Welcome back," [name] stage.

```
import tkinter as tk
from time import time
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()


#FUNCTION FOR LABELS (not necessary but it condenses the code)
def label(a):
    Label(root,text=a,font=("System",15,"bold"),fg="steelblue").pack()



#THIS IS FOR EXTRACTING SPECIFIC DATA FROM THE TEXTFILE

lines = [] #Declare an empty list named "lines"
def specify(x):
    with open ('storefile.txt', 'rt+') as in_file:  #Open file lorem.txt for reading of text data.
        for line in in_file:                       #For each line of text store in a string variable named "line", and
            lines.append(line)                     #add that line to our list of lines.
    label(lines[x])                                #print the list object.

    #[x] allows us to print whatever line we want.

#############################

#THIS IS FOR THE 'ENTER NAME' BUTTON TO STORE NAMES
def store():
    user_entry = distance_text_box.get()
    f=open("storefile.txt", "a")
    f.write (str(user_entry))
    f.close()

#TITLE
label("[INSERT TITLE]")




#CHECKS IF THIS IS THEIR FIRST TIME ON THE APP. IF IT IS, PRINT DESCRIPTION AND ASKS FOR USERNAME
searchfile = open("storefile.txt", "r")
with open ('storefile.txt', 'rt+') as in_file:  #Open file lorem.txt for reading of text data.
    for line in searchfile:                       #For each line of text store in a string variable named "line", and
        if "1" not in line:#IT STORES '1' IN THE TEXTFILE WHEN THE USER FIRST OPENS THE CODE, SO IF '1' ISN'T THERE, THE USER HAS NOT OPENED THE CODE YET
            print("yes")

            Label(root,text="ENTER NAME",font=("System",15,"bold"),fg="steelblue").pack(side=LEFT)#enter name label

            distance_text_box = Entry(root, bd=1)
            distance_text_box.pack()

            searchfile = open("storefile.txt", "a")
            searchfile.write("1\n")
            searchfile.close()

            Button(root, text ="Done!", command=lambda:store()).pack(side=RIGHT)


    elif "1" in line:
        print("no")
        Label(root,text="Welcome back,").pack()
searchfile.close()






#PUT NAME IN TEXTFILE



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are trying to write something to an already open file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are trying to open an already opened file.
Second, if you want to access a file line by line try this:

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
  lines  = f.readlines() #lines is now a list of lines in the file.
```

If you want to add new text to the file you can simply create a list of lines to add and append to it, once the check loop is done, append it to the lines list and write back to the file.